# (PHP) - How to Fetch data in realtime once QR code scanned

Tags: javascript, php

How can I fetch all data in realtime once my QR code show its MAC Address that is also stored in my db? I can display the value of the QR but I want to display the whole row from my db of that scanned MAC Address. I'm using InstaScan btw. I hope that someone can help me regarding this. Thank you!

Here is my code below..

```html
<?php

    session_start();
    include 'config.php';

    !$_SESSION['admin-logged'] ? header("Location: login.php?access denied") : '';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webrtc-adapter/3.3.3/adapter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card p-3">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Scan QR Code:</h2>
                    <video id="preview" width="100%"></video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card p-5">
                    <h3 class="text-center">QR Code Information</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="fields">
                        <!-- THIS IS MY MAC ADDRESS FIELD -->
                        <label for="mac">MAC Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mac" id="mac" readonly class="form-control text-success font-weight-bold">
                        
                        <!-- BUT ALSO I WANT TO DISPLAY THE NAME, LOCATION, ETC IN REALTIME -->
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" readonly>
                        <label for="loc">Location</label>
                        <input type="text" name="loc" id="loc" readonly>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview')});
           Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function(cameras){
               if(cameras.length > 0 ){
                   scanner.start(cameras[0]);
               } else{
                   alert('No cameras found');
               }

           }).catch(function(e) {
               console.error(e);
           });

           scanner.addListener('scan',function(c){
               document.getElementById('mac').value=c;
           });
    </script>
    <script src="main-js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Side note: `header("Location: login.php?access denied")` will not deny access to your page unless followed by `exit();` - otherwise the browser will still be given the content of the rest of the page (even if it doesn't show it on screen, it would be visible through the network tool to anyone who wants to look, or a bot or search engine, or someone visiting your page via PostMan or a similar tool, could still find it and use it. Unless you actually exit the script, PHP will still output the rest of the supposedly restricted page back to the client.)

Comment: Anyway, it's unclear where you're stuck with your question. Are you asking how send the MAC address value to your server? Or how to write a SQL query? Or what? please narrow down the issue and make a more focused question. Also what have you researched or tried so far to try and solve it? See also [ask].

Comment: I guess you will need a PHP endpoint that accepts a http request containing a mac address and returns matching data from the database.  You would then issue a request to that endpoint from your scanner.addEventListener code, probably via AJAX.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your answer and I’m sorry for the unclear question. Once you registered, it automatically gives random MAC address in every user because i dont want name or other information to be stored in QR, just to ensure that the QR is unique. My question is, once I scanned that QR code and once MAC Address is displayed on the first input field, other fields will also automatically fetch in realtime from my database from that mac address. It’s just I don’t really understand AJAX.

Comment: Thank you @James But I dont understand AJAX yet. I’m stuck here at days

Comment: Well the first thing you need to do then is study some AJAX tutorials, try it out, start to understand it, and then try to apply what you've learned to your scenario.

Comment: But, I don’t really know how to query that. Once 1st input shows Mac address, then the value of the textbox will stored in php variable just like this. $textbox = textboxValue. And for the query, SELECT * FROM table WHERE mac_address = ‘$textbox’”;

Comment: Yeah the query looks OK (apart from it should be parameterised), what you need ajax for is to transmit the textbox value to the server without refreshing the page